# Can an opamp have its own voltage regulator?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm wondering if we use batteries instead of stable power supply for the opamp power rails what would be the consequences.

If we use an opamp for precision application would using batteries a bad idea since the battery voltage drifts might effect the opamp output directly?

Comment: Look up the term PSRR. That’s mainly a metric for the AC performance but you get the idea. If you have enough headroom to fit your signal within the lowest battery voltage and how ever much margin the opamp needs to the rail, it’s pretty much job done.

Comment: @winny If the data sheet says the Vcc can be between 5V upto 12V and if I use 9V battery and lest says the output for a fixed input is 1V. Now if the 9V supply rail drops to 8V due to battery draining how can I estimate or predict if the output will ever change? Would simulation be reliable?

Comment: Consider that noise is going to be higher frequency than any change in battery voltage and the opamp can't react fast enough to keep it out. My understanding is that the battery is going to be lower noise than any "stable power supply".

Comment: @DKNguyen Noise can be taken care of by decoupling cap. Im mostly asking for the effect of rail voltage drift.

Comment: @Genzo I'm talking about even with decoupling capacitors.

Comment: That, and check how close to the rails your signals can be. "Bad" opamps needs several volt headroom.

Comment: If there is any comparison involved with a reference voltage which is derived from and influenced by the power supply's voltage you should use the stable power supply or provide for a stable reference additionally.

Comment: Most voltage regulators USE opamps internally :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using the opamp in a **feedback** configuration circuit, which you probably do because you need some precision.

Also assuming that the voltages at inputs and output of the opamp do not exceed what the opamp can handle at the given battery supply voltage. I'm thinking (common mode) input voltage range and output voltage range with a certain load connected.

Then the battery voltage drift should be **irrelevant**.

In a properly designed circuit the gain (and offset) of the opamp will then determine the output voltage, not the supply voltage.

So yes, you **can** add a regulator but I don't think you have any reason to do so. It will only use up some of the battery voltage (and power) while perhaps not improving anything.

What you might need is a "low battery" detection and indicator (for example, a flashing LED) to indicate that the battery voltage has become too low and accuracy might be compromised.

Comment: If the gain of the opamp tries to set the output voltage at 10 V for instance and the supply voltage is 9 V, the supply voltage wins. But for a supply voltage of 15 V or 14.5 V, the output voltage should be 10 V in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

As a kid, I built many a multi-stage bipolar AC_coupled amplifier, using +9v batteries (the big kind, about 3" by 3" by 4"), and the amplifiers always oscillated ----- until I learned to use 5,000uF capacitors on the +9v rail.

In fact, until an uncle suggested VDD filtering using R+C low pass filters like he used in the vacuum-tube receivers he worked with, and I then explored 100_ohm resistors between the first couple of gain stages and the final 3 or 4 stages that used a tiny transformer to drive a tiny speaker, and I placed 5,000uF capacitors on BOTH SIDES of the 100_ohm resistor, I never could experiment with more than 4 stages without oscillation.

Thus with amplifiers having enough gain to bring up the electron-noise to the level to drive a tiny speaker, I needed to strongly isolate the VDD of first couple stages from the VDD of the final (higher current) stages, using 100_ohm resistors and big capacitors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyt6ki.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I could have used UA723 voltage regulators back then, as you are suggesting be used.

Why were the batteries a problem? because the batteries have much higher Rout than a regulated power supply. That high Rout serves as interaction between the final higher current (delta I of 10mA? to drive transformer) stages and the first stages. And you get motorboating, or squealing, like a public address system squeals with acoustic feedback.

To summarize, with enough gain (as I learned to build), the earlier stages in a signal chain need either

(1) their own regulators,

or

(2) the VDD to be heavily filtered with isolation resistors (10 ohm, 100 ohm) and large capacitors.

You may be able to avoid the high-gain-chain oscillation, if you use lantern +6v batteries. Or car batteries.

Comment: Yes, a sensitive circuit can have issues with a weak battery such as a 9V. A simple opamp with feedback may be OK, but it isn't your only risk. Sensors may need biasing, comparators may switch causing step voltage changes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- Small primary batteries can supply AC noise current with DC

  - **proof**: connect any good 1.5V battery to any speaker and listen to 1/f thermal noise
- but Op Amps can reject most AC supply noise (PSRR) but still need attention.
- Op Amp circuit designs are usually based on external impedance ratios and not sensitive DC supply voltage with adequate signal common-mode headroom.
- If using DC as a voltage reference to input then DC stability may be a source of errors.

### Can an opamp have its own voltage regulator?

Yes, but they do not, as this would limit their general purpose usefulness.